# How to write DRY and effective if-statement in golang?

Tags: if-statement, go

I have following code:

```
func main() {
    // counts := make(map[string]int)
    files := os.Args[1:]
    if len(files) == 0 {
        counts := make(map[string]int)
        countLines(os.Stdin, counts)
        fmt.Println("os.Stdin")
        printCounts(counts)
    } else {
        for _, arg := range files {
            counts := make(map[string]int)

            f, err := os.Open(arg)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "dup2: %v\n", err)
                continue
            }
            countLines(f, counts)
            f.Close()
            // print counts of each file
            printCounts(counts)
        }
    }
}
func printCounts(counts map[string]int) {
    //...
}
func countLines(f *os.File, counts map[string]int){
    //...
}
```

where i repeat myself in if-else statement by initiating counts dict twice,
(`counts := make(map[string]int)`) both in if and else.

My question is what is the gopher-way of writing this?

Is that better to do the allocation outside the if-else statment with `new` and do initiation in every block?

Comment: Why don't you simply extract the bodies of if/else into their own functions?

Comment: This is too much about personal opinion, there's no best way to do it. But Sergio is correct, just have a combined `countLines` and `printCounts` function that only takes a file.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it's really make a compact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see much repetition in your code. You could somehow merge both if and else part but I'm not a fan of.

A simple refactor is moving `counts` initialization into your `countLines` function and make it return it.

```
func countLines(f *os.File, counts map[string]int)
```

->

```
func countLines(f *os.File) map[string]int
```

And don't think much about allocations until you are doing a lot (let's say at least 100K allocations) and profile your code before doing little optimizations. Maps will allocate memory not only on `make` but also when you append to them and their hash table is full.